# Withdrawal of Monero from Binance to wallet missing

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

My transfer of Monero from Binance  to mymonerowallet.org is missing. The Binance account was emptied, but the Monero did not deposit to my wallet. The address was correct and I included the payment id. I am new to this and have little experience with any of this. 
Any help to recover the small partial token is greatly appreciated.
No idea if I have CLI or GUI.

Comment: Are you using that particular webwallet? Because the only legitimate webwallet is mymonero.com. Everything else is, most likely, a scam wallet that will steal your funds.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am using mymonerowallet.org.

Comment: I used mymonerowallet.org.  Looks like a bogus site and transfer likely lost.

Comment: It seems so. I am sorry for your loss :/